# How to find database file generated of my application in android device

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I made an application which collects information of device and create a database using SQLite in android. Using file explorer, i can see database of my application in Emulator using Eclipse. I attached the image as shown.

[image]

I want to collect information of my android device. I execute the application in my device. Now i am not able to find neither package name of my application nor database of my application.

Please help?

Comment: use the DDMS View then go to /Data/Data/packagename/databases. I think you can right click to pull the file or if not, you have to use ADB.

Comment: I didn't find package name of my application in my device. i.e. inside Android/Data/Data, my application package doesn't exist

Comment: The picture you posted does not contain enough info. We cannot see the full path of the directory where the packages reside.

Comment: @greenapps This is the picture i took when i saw my results using emulator. I am happy with this result.When i connected my device with eclipse, i didn't see the my device app info into "File explorer" of eclipse. so i went to "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data". I didn't see my app info

Comment: Sorry but that is contradictory. One time you tell that you see. The other time you tell that you don't see. Well we all see that Eclipse shows your package dir with content. Which file explorer app did you use on your device?

Comment: Oh sorry. Now I understand that the picture is of your app on an emulator. It has nothing to do with your app on a real device. Eclipse does not show the package dir of your app on your device. He he, now I understand the situation. The solution is quite simple: on your device your package dir is  /data/data/packagename. You compared different devices/emulators. What a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will only be able to access the database on a physical device if your device is rooted. An emulator gives full access to the databases, where as a device does not, unless it is rooted.

Comment: How to root my device?

Comment: Be careful, rooting your device can cause it to lose its warranty, so proceed with caution. I would advise testing with the emulator to get it right, you shouldn't need to root for this. But if you so wish - http://www.androidcentral.com/root

Comment: No. Any app can access it database files in -mostly- /data/data/apname/databases. No need for a rooted device.

Comment: But i want to see database of my application using android device.Do you know some other way?

Comment: You can write code to access the data, or debug it and view the data like that. If you want to download the database, use the emulator.

Comment: @greenapps i m looking my package name in /storage/emulated/0/android/data but i didn't found. Here there are package of dropbox, twitter but none of my application

Comment: @riggaroo but my application collect database of other apps. So i want database of my device not emulator

Comment: @Yati that is normal. You are looking in /storage...... but you have to look (as I said) in /data/data/packagename. Unfortunately you cannot browse to that with a filebrowser /data is inaccessable for a filebrowser or any other app on a non rooted device. But you can access all files in /data/data/packagename using File or FileInputStream. `File file = getDatabasePath(TABLE_NAME1);`

Comment: You were looking in "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data". But is that the same path as displayed in Eclipse? Note we cannot see that path in Eclipse. Which file explorer do you use?

Comment: @greenapps This is the result of emulator. Thats why we didn't see the result. In my android device, i am using app called "file explorer"

Comment: That was very confusing: you better had posted a picture where your device was connected with Eclipse. Then you could have told us that you could not see your database files in Eclipse and also not on your device. You can read my first post again and try to grab the database files from /data/data/packagename/databases.

Answer (score 2):

You can try shelling into the device from the command line over USB like so:

```
# normal shell on local machine
adb shell
# android shell on device
run-as [your.package.name.here]
cd databases
sqlite3 [database_name]
```

Note that on some devices you do not have access to sqlite3 from the shell like this. In those cases I have copied the database file to the external storage directory (usually `/sdcard`), exited the shell, then used `adb pull` to retrieve it.

```
# android shell on device
cp [database_name] /sdcard
exit
# normal shell on local machine
cd [somewhere]
adb pull /sdcard/[database_name] .
```

Comment: i m using windows. may you tell me command of windows please to do that steps?

Comment: The commands are the same. `cd` and `adb` are the only commands run int he windows shell. The other commands are actually run in Android's shell, which is linux-based.

Comment: using above I'm able to get database from micromax device... (sqlite didn't work in my case, used cp) hence upvote.... thanks